# converting index values into integer tuples in python3

Tags: python, type-conversion, tuples

```
candidatelist = [['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'e', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'n'], ['n', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n']]

check = "e"


mytuplelist = (
["({}, {})".format((index1), (index2)) for index1, value1 in enumerate(candidatelist) for index2, value2 in
 enumerate(value1) if value2 == check])
```

I can collect the index values that I need. I can successfully convert them into a string. However, I dont need a string, I want to create a list of integer tuples (pairs). I have tried several things like this:

```
mytuplelist = ([({}, {})(int(index1), int(index2)) for index1, value1 in enumerate(candidatelist) for index2, value2 in
 enumerate(value1) if value2 == check])
```

But I don't get it to work. Is there a good way of doing this without having to reformat the string? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity without the one-liner

```
candidatelist = [['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'e', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'n'], ['n', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'e', 'n', 'n'], ['n', 'n', 'e', 'e', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n']]

check = "e"

tupleslist = []
for i in enumerate(candidatelist):
    try:
        tupleslist.append((i[0],i[1].index(check)))
    except:
        tupleslist.append((1,0))
```

You get: [(0, 4), (1, 6), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 0), (5, 0), (6, 5), (7, 2)]

Comment: definitely less messy than my attempt. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
mytuplelist = (
[((index1), (index2)) for index1, value1 in enumerate(candidatelist) for index2, value2 in
 enumerate(value1) if value2 == check])
print(mytuplelist)
```

the above code will return the all indexes in sublist, if you want just index of first occurrence then try below code:

```
mytuplelist = (
[(index1 , value1.index(check)) for index1, value1 in enumerate(candidatelist) if check in value1])
print(mytuplelist)
```

Comment: I have tested your code, it works great. Thank you!